# Python Distribute List of Tuple Items by Matching Recursively

Tags: python, recursion

I'm trying to write a recursive function that will look for matching items in a list of tuples, and distribute them into groups.  An example list could be:

```
l = [(1,2),(2,3),(4,6),(3,5),(7,9),(6,8)]
```

And the intent is to end with three sublists in the form of:

```
l = [(1,2),(2,3),(3,5)],[(4,6),(6,8)],[7,9]]
```

This appears to be an ideal situation for a recursive function, but I haven't made it work yet.  Here is what I have written so far:

```
count = 0
def network(index_list, tuples_list, groups, count):
    if len(index_list) > 0:
        i = 0
        for j in range (len(index_list)):
            match = set(tuples_list[groups[count][i]]) & set(tuples_list[index_list[j]])
            if len(match) > 0:
                groups[count].append(index_list[j])
                index_list.pop(j)
                i += 1
            else:
                count += 1
                groups.append([])
                groups[count].append(index_list[0])
                network(index_list, tuples_list, groups, count)
    else:
        return groups
```

Also I'm pretty certain this question is different than the one marked duplicate.  I'm looking for a **recursive** solution that keeps all of the tuples intact, in this case by pushing around their indices with append and pop.  I'm positive there's an elegant and recursive solution to this problem.

Comment: It looks like you want us to write some code for you. While many users are willing to produce code for a coder in distress, they usually only help when the poster has already tried to solve the problem on their own. A good way to demonstrate this effort is to include the code you've written so far, example input (if there is any), the expected output, and the output you actually get (console output, tracebacks, etc.). The more detail you provide, the more answers you are likely to receive. Check the [FAQ] and [ask].

Comment: Thanks, I've added what code I've managed to write.  The problem is it continually crashes my computer, so I wouldn't recommend it.

Comment: You're not returning your recursive calls.

Comment: Ok I'm trying different configurations of returns, but it hasn't helped yet.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I'm not sure recursion is helpful here. It was an interesting thought experiment, so I tried it out, but my recursive function only ever needs one run-through.

**Modified based on comment to only match the first two data points of a tuple**

```
import copy

#Inital 1-item groups
def groupTuples(tupleList):
    groups = []
    for t in tupleList:
        groups.append([t])
    return groups

#Merge two groups
def splice(list1, list2, index):
    for item in list2:
        list1.insert(index, item)
        index += 1
    return list1

def network(groups = []):
    #Groups get modified by reference, need a shallow copy for reference
    oldGroups = copy.copy(groups) 
    for group in groups:
        for index, secondGroup in enumerate(groups):
            if group == secondGroup:
                #Splice can get caught in a loop if passed the same item twice.
                continue 
            #Last item of First Group matches First item of Second Group
            if group[-1][1] == secondGroup[0][0]:
                splice(group, secondGroup, len(group))
                groups.pop(index)
            #First item of First Group matches Last item of Second Group
            elif group[0][0] == secondGroup[-1][1]:
                splice(group, secondGroup, 0)
                groups.pop(index)

    if groups == oldGroups:
        return groups #No change.
    else:
        return network(groups)


l = [(1,2,0),(2,3,1),(4,6,2),(3,5,3),(1,7,4),(7,9,5),(6,8,6),(12, 13,7),(5, 12,8)]
result = network(groupTuples(l))
print result
```

Result: `[[(1, 2, 0), (2, 3, 1), (3, 5, 3), (5, 12, 8), (12, 13, 7)], [(1, 7, 4), (7, 9, 5)], [(4, 6, 2), (6, 8, 6)]]`

It does run the matching algorithm over the dataset multiple times, but I've yet to see a configuration of data where the second iteration yields any changes, so not sure recursion is necessary here.

Comment: This is fantastic!  It works great.  Now what I'm trying (and failing) to do is output the indices in a matching group structure.  However for some reason I don't understand, simply including the index in the original tuple won't work, even though all of the indices are unique.  For example: `(1.25, 2.35, 1)` and `(1.25, 3.57, 2)`  What happens is that all of the groups get squashed into one flat list.  Any thoughts?

Comment: The code above tries to match the first and last items of various groups. If you modify the tuples with extraneous data, it will try to match those. For example, if you have the tuples `(2, 3, 1)` and `(5, 6, 2)`, it will match the last 2 in the second tuple with the first 2 in the first tuple, forming the group `[(5, 6, 2), (2, 3, 1)]`. It doesn't distinguish between the different meanings of the data.

Comment: Hmm, I suppose it could work the way you tried, with slight modifications. I don't like mixing data with distinct meanings into a single piece of data, but tuples are immutable, so it could be done. I'll update the code with an example.

Comment: Nice update!  Actually for the data set I'm working with recursion is making a difference.  Without recursion I end up with 20 groups (some with only 1 index).  With recursion it's down to 10.  Now I'm trying to find a way to get it down to 3.

Comment: Can you post your data set? I'd be curious to see it.

Comment: Certainly.  I'm using working with approx. 100 curves in Rhino, that are currently in 3 contiguous groups.  Said another way, each group contains some 30 curves that share end points, and are not touching either of the other groups.  The idea is to compare curve end points to group curves (since the curve configurations change over time).  This is a sample tuple from the dataset: `(<Rhino.Geometry.Point3d object at 0x0000000000008D24 [15.694882866766,26.1348326049785,0]>, <Rhino.Geometry.Point3d object at 0x0000000000008D25 [16.0470078687842,26.0586264478253,0]>, 23)`

Comment: Interesting. You may want to add some fuzziness to the matching, like +/- 0.01% or so, to find points that are close, but not exact. However, the code I posted does not guarantee the maximal group length, it's just a simple fast and dirty matching algorithm. The inefficient way would be to pass it every permutation of the data ordering and find which one provides the optimal result, but, dependent on the size of the dataset, that could take a while to process. For anything more complex, I suggest doing some research on graph theory.

Comment: Also, sorting the data before matching should help a bit.